# Loop through components and return in switch case (React.js)

Tags: reactjs, loops, switch-statement, components, case

### Brief description

So thanks to the [svg-to-react-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-to-react-cli) script I have 73 components for my icons. 
Now, if I want to call these icons, I can individually call each one I want to use. **But this is not what I want.**

What I want is to call only **one** component where I add a 'name' value to. 
**e.g.:** < Icon name='Name of one of  the 73 components I wish to call' />

### My question

How do I loop through multiple components inside a directory, and return them inside a switch case?
**This is how all my 73 components inside the directory look like**

```
import React from 'react';

export default function NAMEOFICON(props) {
  return (
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width={100} height={100} {...props}>
      ...CONTENT OF SVG...
    </svg>
  );
}
```

### This is what I have

```
import React from 'react';
import ALLCOMPONENTS from 'DIRECTORY WITH COMPONENTS'

// HERE I WANT TO LOOP THROUGH COMPONENTS AND ADD THEM IN THIS SWITCH
const getPath = (name, props) => {
  switch (name) {
    case 'NAME OF THE COMPONENT':
      ... HERE COMES CONTENT OF COMPONENT...
    default:
      return <path />;
  }
};
// HERE I CREATE A CONST TO LATER CALL THE DESIRED COMPONENT BY NAME
const Icon = ({
  name = '',
  style = {},
  fill = 'currentColor',
  viewBox = '',
  width = '20px',
  className = 'icon icon' + name,
  height = '20px'
}) => (
    {NAME OF COMPONENT({ fill })}
);

export default Icon ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's incorrect to rely on directory contents in client-side script because there's none in bundled application.

A proper way is to have a 'barrel' module that re-exports all submodules:

*icon-components/index.js*

```
export { default as FooIcon } from './foo-icon';
export { default as BarIcon } from './bar-icon';
```

And use it like:

```
import * as icons from './icon-components';

...

for (const [iconComponentName, IconComponent] of Object.entries(icons)) { ... }
```

It makes sense to generate index.js similarly to how icon components were generated, i.e. in Node.js environment where there's an access to file system. `svg-to-react-cli` could be forked for this purpose, or this could be a separate script.

Comment: Hi there! I completely understand. However; I want to create a package. So later on, I just have to 'npm install mypackage' and then do 'import Icon from mypackage and then all I have to do is <Icon name='name' />. What I want in the end result; is only have to add a new icon component without having to handle any more manual work. + with your method; I do have to manually export write each export for each icon and I try to make this go as automatically as possible.

Comment: As it was mentioned, you need to do this in *Node.js script* to generate index.js automatically. You can write it from scratch or fork svg-to-react-cli and modify it to generate index.js in addition to component classes. This is out of scope of original question that addresses React part. The answer for React part is that you need to have this index.js file any way to make your package work seamlessly for users. Consider asking another question that is aimed purely at Node.js if you have specific problems with modifying svg-to-react-cli for your needs.

Comment: As for Node.js script, should be something like `let indexContents = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/icon-components').map(file => { let filename = path.parse(file).name; return "export {default as " + convertKebabToPascalCase(filename) + "} from './" + filename + "'").join('\n'); fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/icon-components/index.js', indexContents)`.

Comment: Okay; thanks for the information! I'm gonna try this and set your question as answered: as this is apparently the proper way to do what I want to achieve. Thank you!

Comment: Hi there, sorry for coming back so late. I'm a bit stuck trying follow your answer. I have done everything you said for the React part (let's forget about the node.js thing, I'm gonna take care of that later). So in my components folder I have an index.js exporting everything. In my Icon.js I import * as Icons from my folder and have copied your for loop to test it. Now when I console.log the 'iconComponentName' I get it's name; but doing the same for IconComponent returns undefined. I can return the name of the component, but not it's data. What am I forgetting here?

Comment: Most likely you don't have `default` export in icon modules or you wrote exports incorrectly in `index`. Another possible explanation for `undefined` exports is circular dependency but I don't think it's suitable here.  I would expect it to work if everything is done correctly. See https://codesandbox.io/s/xlqwwwonzq for example.

Comment: It was indeed the lack of the world 'default'. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be...

Have an index file that exports all your icons.

```
export { SomeIcon } from './someIcon.jsx';
export { SomeOtherIcon } from './someOtherIcon.jsx';
```

Import all the icons into `Icons`

```
import * as Icons from 'icons';
```

You can grab the component using the name as a key on `Icons`

```
const Icon = Icons[props.name];
return <Icon {...otherProps} />;
```

Comment: This is indeed the solution that is also advised by estus