# How to render one array item based on name props in React

Tags: reactjs, loops, switch-statement, case

### Brief description

Thanks to previous help been able to render multiple icon components in my React project. Except I don't want to have them all rendered at once, but just the one I am calling based on a name prop.

I am a bit confused as to where I have to pass props to achieve what I want. I have tried to work with a 'switch/case' as you can see in title '**What I tried**', but I don't know how loop multiple cases.

### What I have

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Icon from  './library/icons/Icon';
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
               <div className='App'>
                   <Icon iconName='Icon1' />
                </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

**Icon.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import * as icons from './icons' 

function IconList({iconName}) {

    const GetIcons = [];
    for (const [name, icon] of Object.entries(icons)) {
        GetIcons.push({name, icon})
    }
    const MapIcons = GetIcons.map(({name, icon}) => {
        return (
            <div>{name} {icon()}</div>
        )
    });
    console.log(GetIcons)
    return (
        <div>{MapIcons}</div>
    )
}
const Icon = ({iconName}) => (
    <IconList />
);

export default Icon;
```

### What this does

This now renders **all** my SVG icon components that I import. My **MapIcons** arrow function loops and renders the name of the components and the function that renders the svg icon.

### What I want to achieve

- Call only one icon based on the iconName prop (as shown in App.js)
- Have a list of props like 'fill='currentColor' that I pass to my icons.

### What I tried

I tried to loop inside a Switch so that I had each function as a case. But I already didn't know what to do to pass the props to the function.

```
function IconList({}) {

    const GetIcons = [];
    for (const [name, icon] of Object.entries(icons)) {
        GetIcons.push({name, icon})
    }
    const SwitchIcons = (iconName, props) => {
        switch (iconName) {
            const MapIcons = GetIcons.map(({name, icon}) => {
                case {name}:
                    return (
                        {icon()}
                    )
            });
        }
    )
}

const Icon = ({
  iconName = '',
  stroke = 'currentColor',
  strokeLinecap = 'round',
  strokeLinejoin = 'round',
  strokeWidth = '3px',
  fill = 'currentColor',
  viewBox = '0 0 100 100',
  width = '100px',
  className = 'icon icon' + name,
  height = '100px'
}) => (
  <div className={className}>
   {SwitchIcons(iconName, { stroke })}
  </div>
);

export default Icon;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` statement was listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53537465/3731501) only for example how icon entries can be iterated, there's no need to push items to another array because `Object.entries` already returns an array. `switch` statement is needed only when there are explicit conditions to list.

```
const Icon = (/*...*/) => {
  const IconComponent = icons[iconName];
  <div className={className}>
   {IconComponent && <IconComponent stroke={stroke} />}
  </div>
};

export default Icon;
```

Given `icons` object contains a map of components, `IconList`, `GetIcons` and `SwitchIcons` aren't needed.

Comment: Oh my god it was that simple.. Thank you so much for everything today estus. You've been a great help and I've learned a lot.